# Update controls created in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, design-patterns

I have two threads.

Thread 1: WPF thread. Shows a Window with all the information. 
Thread 2: Loops constantly, receiving information & updates the Window in thread 1.

I have the following interfaces.

```
IModuleWindow
{
    void AddModule(IModule module);
    void RemoveModule(IModule module);
}

IModule
{
    UserControl GetSmallScreen();
    UserControl GetBigScreen();
}
```

IModuleWindow is implemented by the WPF window in Thread 1
IModule is implemented by an object, is instantiated in Thread 2, and then sent to thread 1.

I want to Add the UserControls in IModule to the Window object in thread 1, and show them. IModule objects get updated constantly in thread 2 and they have to change their text.

Basically the idea is that this program is supposed to show the state of objects in thread 2 , which gets updated constantly.

What is the best way to accomplish this in WPF?

Comment: Are you trying to show controls, created at another thread, in window, created at main WPF thread?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to use controls created at another thread, thats what I want ideally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the best idea is to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58), with the very handy `ReportProgress` method and `ProgressChanged` event.

The `ProgressChanged` event is raised on the GUI thread, so you can perform your updates to the GUI directly. Here's how you code should look like:

```
// initialize the worker
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();


// thread 2 (BackgroundWorker) 
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // main loop
    while(true) 
    {
        // time-consuming work
        // raise the event; use the state object to pass any information you need
        ReportProgress(0, state);
    }
}

// this code will run on the GUI thread
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // get your state back
    object state = e.UserState;
    // update GUI with state
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this, but how would Backgroundworker add UserControls created at another thread? I don't have full control of what the content of the user control will be/which controls will be updated in that user control.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: Why don't you create these controls on the GUI thread once, pass them to the backgroundworker, change them, and then update them back on the GUI thread? Or are you using some third-party code?

Comment: hm, would it make sense to just pass the 'Type' of the user-control I want to instantiate in ProgressChanged, instantiate it, and then cast it to the appropriate interface, and then use that?

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: You should only create controls on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

[It helped](http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html) me lot to understand what i must do.

The scenario must be like that:

```
ObservableCollection images = new ObservableCollection();
TaskFactory tFactory = new TaskFactory();

tFactory.StartNew(() =>
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    //GET IMAGE Path FROM SERVER
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher
          .BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
          {
            // UPDATE PROGRESS BAR IN UI
          });

     images.Add(("");
   }    
  }).ContinueWith(t =>
     {
       if (t.IsFaulted)
       {
          // EXCEPTION IF THREAD IS FAULT
          throw t.Exception;
        }
      System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher
       .BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
       {
          //PROCESS IMAGES AND DISPLAY
       });
    });
```

You must use [System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) for updating UI in WPF.

Comment: This is one of the worse examples of TPL usage I ever seen. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be nice to be able to use controls created at another thread,
>   thats what I want ideally

The short answer: forget it.

A UI control belongs to a single UI thread only. The best you can do here, is to **create** controls in main thread, prepare data in background thread, and update controls' properties in main (UI) thread again.

For data preparation I recommend use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).